# Magento - rearrange welcome message, searchbox and catalog nav using local.xml

Tags: magento

i'm trying to achieve a layout wherein the default welcome message sits on top of the search box followed by the catalog nav similar to what they have [here](http://cms.template-help.com/magento_28316/).

i was hoping to do this through the local.xml file. so far i have this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<layout>
  <default> 

    <!-- add the local stylesheet -->
    <reference name="head">
      <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/local.css</stylesheet></action>
    </reference>

    <reference name="header">
      <action method="unsetChild"><alias>topSearch</alias></action>
      <action method="insert"><blockName>top.search</blockName><sublingName>catalog.topnav</sublingName><after>1</after></action>
    </reference>   

  </default>  
</layout>
```

i was able to unset the searchbox but i couldn't make it insert before the catalog nav - nothing happens. i also tried inserting it this way

```
    <reference name="top.nav">
      <action method="insert"><blockName>top.search</blockName><sublingName>catalog.topnav</sublingName><after>1</after></action>
    </reference>
```

but it still doesn't work. what could i be doing wrong here?

i'm getting really confused here, is this kind of approach okay to do? i checked the header.phtml and saw that i only have to switch the lines for the default welcome message and searchbox and i'm done! but i guess this would mean that i would have to make a copy
of the header.phtml to my own theme. would this be a better approach?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a copy of header.phtml for your own theme. As you've seen it controls the order of output and there is no magic that can make it change otherwise - except for hacking it with javascript but that's worse...

The purpose of having different folders for each theme is to allow exactly this sort of override so use it to your advantage.

Comment: thanks clockworkgeek! i'll go with your advice, this clears things up for me